# Team City error mscorlib.dll duplicate reference building Xamarin Android application

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library, teamcity-8.0

I am getting below error when building in Team City an Android empty new application using Xamarin:

> [Csc] c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll error
>   CS1703: An assembly with the same identity 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' has already been
>   imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.

The solution is composed of a Portable Class Library (PCL) that references

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7
>   (.NET SDK)

```
  this folder contains mscorlib.dll from Microsoft (Product Name: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.30319...) so assuming is referencing it
```

and there is an Android Project that references the previous PCL project and also references

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll

```
   this mscorlib.dll is Mono one (Product Name: Mono Common Language Infraestructure)
```

As I said it is a new empty application and it is configured the same way (VS projects and Team City build) as an existing Android application that builds with no errors.
The application builds locally with no errors or warnings

Any ideas on how to solve this Team City build problem?

Answer (score 1):

After many changes trial and error changes what finally make the error disappear was to change the framework version number in the .csproj

From

> ```
> <AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>True</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
> <TargetFrameworkVersion>v5.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
> ```

To

> ```
> <AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>False</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
> <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0.3</TargetFrameworkVersion>
> ```